# How to set a specific Height of the container which wrap ListView.Builder

Tags: flutter

ListView.builder Need a size to be displayed, so often we put a container as parent of ListView.builder to display correctly the list.
The problem are 2.
The height we set are different per different device and I noticed problem with the last element of the list if there is a BottomNavigation bar that will cover the last element of the list
this is an image:
[image]

sorry if I cover but for privacy I need...
anyway.. as you can see the last item of the list is covered by the BottomNav Bar
how to define and fix this issue?
Of could I could resize the container and make it more smaller but the problem will be with different device.

Answer (score 1):

you can wrap your `ListView.builder` with `Expanded` instead of Container. and more better to put it in Column then wrap it with Expanded widget.

Comment: With that I get:
RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderLayoutBuilder#48976 relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
Failed assertion: line 1785 pos 12: 'hasSize'

Answer (score 1):

you should use `MediaQuery` under BuildContext then you can get the height and the width then do some math and that all you need to make a responsive app the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2Cfo.jpg) of the app

```
void main() async {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(     
      home: Scaffold(
          body: Center(
        child: TheSize(),
      )),
    );
  }
}

class TheSize extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    var height = size.height;
    var width = size.width;
    return Container(
      height: height / 2,
      width: width / 1.5,
      color: Colors.blue,
      child: Text('the height = $height | the width = $width '),
    );
  }
}
```